# I can't find duplicate string with python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to find duplicate string from 2 file with python by print `resrc_lst[i]` from json file and `line.split(' ' ,2)[2]` split string from text file. This is my code.

```
for i in range(len(resrc_lst)):
    print(resrc_lst[i])

    if(resrc_lst[i] != ""):   

        with open("clicker_out.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as search_lst: 
            for line in search_lst:

                if resrc_lst[i].strip() in line.split(' ' ,2)[2]:
                    print(line.split(' ' ,2)[2])
```

I'm sure 2 file have all duplicate string when I run the code it show like this.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\4

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshhttp

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\(Default)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wshelper

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wwancfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\p2pnetsh

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\hnetmon

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nettrace

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\rpc

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wlancfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshipsec

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\whhelper

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\netiohlp

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\napmontr

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\WcnNetsh

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\dot3cfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\fwcfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\authfwcfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshwfp

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\2

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\dhcpclient

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\(Default)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\(Default)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Roaming\RefreshProcName

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HandleMgr

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Service\Enable

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\TransportDllPath

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\CryptoAlgo

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Roaming

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\MaxPendingDownloads

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Service\PolicyRefreshInProgress

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\CacheMgr\Publication

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\MaxSimultaneousDownloads

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager\BlockSize

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\CooperativeCaching

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Publisher

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\MaxPendingOffers

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\UserenvDebugLevel

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\MaxSimultaneousUploads

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager\Restricted\Seed

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Download

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\CacheMgr\Republication

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\Connection

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager\Restricted

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Roaming\RefreshDllName

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\ServerRole

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Protocol

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager\DiscoveryProviderDllPath

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager\MinBackoffWindow

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\DoNotUseSSL

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\HostedCache\ClientAuth

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Peers\Connection

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\TransportDllPath

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Service

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Discovery

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\PolicyProvider

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\Upload

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\SecurityManager\NumBlocksPerSegment

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DownloadManager\UtilityIndex

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\Roaming\ForceRoamingDetect

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PeerDist\DiscoveryManager\RepubQuorumSize

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\4
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\4

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshwfp
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshwfp

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\dhcpclient
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\dhcpclient

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wshelper
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wshelper

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshhttp
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshhttp

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\fwcfg
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\fwcfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\authfwcfg
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\authfwcfg

C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows\system32

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\SourcePath
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\SourcePath

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DevicePath
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DevicePath

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Setup

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\2
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\2

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\netiohlp
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\netiohlp

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\whhelper
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\whhelper

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\hnetmon
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\hnetmon

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\rpc
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\rpc

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\dot3cfg
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\dot3cfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\LdapClientIntegrity
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\LdapClientIntegrity

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\UseOldHostResolutionOrder
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\UseOldHostResolutionOrder

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\UseHostnameAsAlias
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\ldap\UseHostnameAsAlias

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\napmontr
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\napmontr

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\IPSEC\Policy\Local
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\IPSEC\Policy\Local

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshipsec
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nshipsec

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nettrace
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\nettrace

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\WcnNetsh
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\WcnNetsh

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\p2pnetsh
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\p2pnetsh

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wlancfg
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wlancfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wwancfg
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NetSh\wwancfg

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\iphlpsvc\Config
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\iphlpsvc\Config

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\iphlpsvc\config\Connectivity_Platform_Enabled
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\iphlpsvc\config\Connectivity_Platform_Enabled

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.4!7\캰=谘=齎
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.4!7\캰=谘=齎

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.4!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.4!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\p2pcollab.dll
C:\Windows\System32\p2pcollab.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.4!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.44.3.4!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\p2pcollab.dll
C:\Windows\System32\p2pcollab.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.47.1.1!7\(Default)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.47.1.1!7\(Default)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.47.1.1!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.47.1.1!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\QAGENTRT.DLL
C:\Windows\System32\QAGENTRT.DLL

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.47.1.1!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.47.1.1!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\QAGENTRT.DLL
C:\Windows\System32\QAGENTRT.DLL

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.64.1.1!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.64.1.1!7\Name

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.64.1.1!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.64.1.1!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll
C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.64.1.1!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.64.1.1!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll
C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.1!7\ 0\Cryptﮐ
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.1!7\ 0\Cryptﮐ

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.1!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.1!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll
C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.1!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.1!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll
C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.2!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.2!7\Name

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.2!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.2!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll
C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.2!7\Name
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\OID\EncodingType 0\CryptDllFindOIDInfo\1.3.6.1.4.1.311.67.1.2!7\Name

C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll
C:\Windows\System32\fveui.dll

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NapAgent\LocalConfig
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NapAgent\LocalConfig

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\(Default)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\(Default)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enroll\HcsGroups
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enroll\HcsGroups

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enroll\HcsGroups\(Default)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enroll\HcsGroups\(Default)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enroll\HcsGroups\(Default)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enable Tracing
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Enable Tracing

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Tracing Level
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\LocalConfig\Tracing Level

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Description

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Registration Date

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Validator Clsid

...
```

I print 2 value in code it should show same string in 2 line. why some line not show duplicate string.

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by "all function should" - "some function not duplicate"? Expand vs duplicate confuses me. Also, what's your input data and what's in your file? Obviously the program has found a duplicate and is printing lines, isn't this the desired behavior?

Comment: I had edit it . I write code for string matching only not about function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the **in** operator and that is not used for checking duplicated strings.

Here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Description

String HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617 appears in string HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\napagent\Qecs\79617\Description but is not duplicated

You could try with:

```
if resrc_lst[i].strip() == line.split(' ' ,2)[2]:
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to strip all string too.  
if resrc_lst[i].strip() == line.split(' ' ,2)[2].strip():